# Python package through setup.py install

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, homebrew

I am trying to install a package via `python setup.py install`, from which I get this. **(Is the `build/lib` does not exist a problem?)**

[image]

but then when I try to import it, the module cannot be found. Indeed, when I go to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, there is no `PyDP` folder there! However, to deepen the mystery, when I do a `pip uninstall`, `pip` seems to think that the package is there; however, there is an error since the package is not actually there:

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated. I am using a Homebrewed Python, and `which python` gets me `/usr/local/bin/python`. **(Is this an issue?)** Thanks.

Comment: Python seems to be installed correctly. Is the code for the Python module you're trying to install available anywhere?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/aroth85/pydp/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an error in the source code of the package.

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
      name='PyDP',
      version='0.2.3',
      description='A Python library for implementing Dirichlet process mixture models.',
      author='Andrew Roth',
      author_email='andrewjlroth@gmail.com',
      url='https://bitbucket.org/aroth85/pydp',
      package_dir = {'': 'lib'},
      packages=find_packages(),
      license = 'GPL v3'
     )
```

Note that `find_packages` is not passed any parameters. By changing this to `find_packages('lib')` things seem to install as expected. Although I'm far from a setuptools expert, so there may be a better way to do this.